# respondsToSelector failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, callback, selector

I have an XML callback selector that seems to fail at the `respondsToSelector` test and I am not sure why.  Why is the call failing?

The callback is set like so:

```
[handler setXMLCallBackDelegate:self :@selector(gotXMLCallback)];
```

The callback is defined like so (in calling class):

```
-(void)gotXMLCallback:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"CALLBACK YAY");
}
```

And the callback is called using this code (from within handler):

```
if (gotXMLCallback && gotXMLCallbackSelector && [gotXMLCallback respondsToSelector:gotXMLCallbackSelector]) {
    (void) [gotXMLCallback performSelector:gotXMLCallbackSelector withObject:self];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon is part of the selector, so it should be `@selector(gotXMLCallback:)`.

Answer (score 0):

To stablish a selector you should call it

```
[gotXMLCallback performSelector:@selector(gotXMLCallbackSelector:) withObject:self];
```